# Fastest way to check if two List<T> are equal

Tags: c#, .net

I have two Lists

`ListA<Emp>` and `ListB<Emp>` 
both are having 1000 records.

`Emp` is an object of Employee Class. Below is my `Employee` class

```
public class Employee
{
    int ID = 0;
    string Name = String.Empty;
    string Dept = String.Empty;
    string Address = String.Empty;
    int Age = 0;
    string Email = String.Empty;
}
```

I want to verify if both the Lists are equal. The Emp objects may be placed in different order. Also, there might be several Emp objects which are having exactly same info in both the list. I have to verify those also.

I tried to sort the lists and compared using `SequenceEqual`

```
Enumerable.SequenceEqual(ListA.OrderBy(s => s), ListB.OrderBy(s => s)
```

I am getting below error

```
At least one object must implement IComparable.
Exception Stack trace is as below 

   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectComparer`1.Compare(T x, T y)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.CompareKeys(Int32 index1, Int32 index2)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.QuickSort(Int32[] map, Int32 left, Int32 right)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual[TSource](IEnumerable`1 first, IEnumerable`1 second, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual[TSource](IEnumerable`1 first, IEnumerable`1 second)
```

How can I implement this ? Also it will be better if you guys can provide me the fastest way of doing this because the number of objects in List may grow to 10 million.
Thanks for your help !

**EDIT:** Every employee must be in both list, order does not matter. But, if ListA contains same employee object 5 times (that means some duplicate entries), and ListB contains the employee object 4 times, then ListA and ListB are not equal.

Comment: Equals means that every employee is in both lists or must the order also be the same (what `SequenceEqual` suggests)?

Comment: Do you have `IEquatable<Employee>` implemented first of all?

Comment: What do you want to order the list by? Sorting `Employee` objects does not make sense by itself.

Comment: every employee will be in both list, order does not matter. But, if ListA contains same employee object 5 times (that means some duplicate entries), and ListB contains the employee object 4 times, then ListA and ListB are not equal.

Comment: If you need the number of instances duplicate to match then I think you need to sort first.  See my answer.

Comment: @Bunyip: In general, please don't comment such important details only but edit (also) your question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, sorry for that. Edited my question.

Comment: At 10 million if each item is 100 bytes and two list that is 2 GB in memory.   How much memory is available to the application?   If you need to preserve count but NOT order then do each List as a Dictionary as in Tonr anser.

Comment: This is exact scenario I had in my project and @Tim Schmelter's answer helped me to fix it. Good Job!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best complexity is O(N)
Following realization with using HashSet:

Class with implementation of GetHashCode and Equals:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID = 0;
    public string Name = String.Empty;
    public string Dept = String.Empty;
    public string Address = String.Empty;
    public int Age = 0;
    public string Email = String.Empty;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return
            ID.GetHashCode() ^
            (Name ?? String.Empty).GetHashCode() ^
            (Dept ?? String.Empty).GetHashCode() ^
            (Address ?? String.Empty).GetHashCode() ^
            Age.GetHashCode() ^
            (Email ?? String.Empty).GetHashCode()
            ;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Employee other = obj as Employee;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        return ID == other.ID &&
                Name == other.Name &&
                Dept == other.Dept &&
                Address == other.Address &&
                Age == other.Age &&
                Email == other.Email;
    }
}
```

Function to compare lists:

```
public static bool CompareLists(List<Employee> list1, List<Employee> list2)
{
    if (list1 == null || list2 == null)
        return list1 == list2;

    if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
        return false;
    Dictionary<Employee, int> hash = new Dictionary<Employee, int>();
    foreach (Employee employee in list1)
    {
        if (hash.ContainsKey(employee))
        {
            hash[employee]++;
        }
        else
        {
            hash.Add(employee, 1);
        }
    }

    foreach (Employee employee in list2)
    {
        if (!hash.ContainsKey(employee) || hash[employee] == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        hash[employee]--;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Need to handle multiple employees, but I like not sorting but hashing.

Comment: HashSet based not give an exact comparison.  If ListA has EmpA 3 times and EmpB 4 times and ListB has EmpA 4 times and EmpB 3 times this solution will determine equals.  But maybe this is what OP wants.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `SequenceEqual`  with a custom `IEqualityComparer<Employee>`:

```
class EmployeeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
{
    public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;

        bool equals = x.ID==y.ID && x.Name == y.Name && x.Dept == y.Dept 
            && x.Address == y.Address && x.Age == y.Age && x.Email == y.Email;
        return equals;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return int.MinValue;

        int hash = 19;
        hash = hash + obj.ID.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash + obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash + obj.Dept.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash + obj.Address.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash + obj.Age.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash + obj.Email.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Now it's so simple:

```
listA.SequenceEqual(ListB, new EmployeeComparer());
```

If the order is not important and you only want to know if all employees are in both lists you can use `HashSet<Employee>.SetEquals` to determine if both lists contain the same people:

```
var empComparer =  new EmployeeComparer();
bool bothEqual = new HashSet<Employee>(ListA, empComparer)
      .SetEquals(new HashSet<Employee>(ListB, empComparer));
```

Comment: Any reason not to implement `IComparable<>` (and perhaps `IEquatable<>`) directly on the `Employee` class?

Comment: @siride: All Linq methods like `Distinct`, `Except`, `Intersect` etc pp. are expecting an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: Btw, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516.aspx), if using the same comparer this is a O(n) operation.

Comment: Does not address number of duplicate matching.  That requirement was not clear in original post.   OP added a comment.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, this works great except the duplicate matching thing. Sorry that, this duplicate matching thing was not in original Post (but in Comments). Now I have edited that.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: if you don't provide an equality comparer, it uses the default, which checks for `IEquatable` on the type being compared: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. This is exact I needed. But "listA.SequenceEqual(ListB, new EmployeeComparer());" gives me error "SequenceEqual is not found for listA". However I used HashSet because Lists are not in a particular order.

Comment: @MAC: then you had not added `using System.Linq;` to your code file.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers in the list are going to grow enormous (10M), you are probably going to have to consider parallelization of the look-up to get an acceptable query time.

Consider using [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx).

Some more clarity on what you mean by 'equal' would be good. How complex is the equivalence check? Are you checking that the *objects* are the same or that the objects *values* are the same?

Another consideration would be this; if the number of elements are going to become large, could you consider moving this check down from .NET into your database - perhaps as a stored procedure? You may find it executes more efficiently there.

Comment: objects values will also be same

Comment: @Bunyip. If you want to do the check in code without parallelisaion, Tims answer above is the way to go.. but, if the numbers get large it's going to slow down. You either have to parallelize in .NET or move it down to the sproc. I would go with the latter. Syntactically, SequenceEqual is elegant, but consider what that is _actually_ going to execute as - probabably a nested for loop.

Comment: @siride, Bunyip asked what the fastest way was to compare two lists. That's a performance question IMHO. But, maybe I misinterpreted. SequenceEqual is fast to _write_ but may become very slow to _execute_.

Comment: @siride no prob. We are working on performance optimization in our app at the moment, so this question is very relevant to me. We've found that when the numbers of elements are small, it's faster to stay in .NET (linq to objects, avoid DB round trips), but when they get large, we are quicker going to the database (one trip, optimized query). We've also had to be careful with using parellelism in .NET as we can exhaust our thread pool very fast. It's case by case really.

Answer (score 1):

reduce the list to a scalar type: int, string, ....

```
L1.Select(x => x.K).ToArray()
```

use the except method

```
L1.Select(x => x.K).ToArray().Except(L1.Select(x => x.K).ToArray())
```

If the count of the resulting set is 0 then the List are equals

```
L1.Select(x => x.K).ToArray().Except(L1.Select(x => x.K).ToArray()).Count()
```

All together

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        List<O> L1 = new List<O>{
            new O {K = 1, V = "abcd"},
            new O {K = 2, V = "efgh"}
        };
        List<O> L2 = new List<O>{
            new O {K = 1, V = "abcd"}
        };
        List<O> L3 = new List<O>{
            new O {K = 1, V = "abcd"},
            new O {K = 3, V = "ijkl"}
        };
        List<O> L4 = new List<O>{
            new O {K = 2, V = "efgh"},
            new O {K = 1, V = "abcd"}

        };

        Console.WriteLine(L1.Select(x => x.K).ToArray().Except(L1.Select(x => x.K).ToArray()).Count());
        Console.WriteLine(L1.Select(x => x.K).ToArray().Except(L2.Select(x => x.K).ToArray()).Count());
        Console.WriteLine(L1.Select(x => x.K).ToArray().Except(L3.Select(x => x.K).ToArray()).Count());
        Console.WriteLine(L1.Select(x => x.K).ToArray().Except(L4.Select(x => x.K).ToArray()).Count());

    }
} 

public class O {
    public int K { get; set; }
    public String V { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what it says.
Implement IComparable on the class Employee
Also need to override Equals
Due to potentially a large number of calls to GetHashCode save it and only calculate on changes.
Tested

[IComparable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IComparable.aspx)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<Person> PLa = new List<Person>();
    List<Person> PLb = new List<Person>();

    PLa.Add(new Person { Age = 3, Name = "Jim"});
    PLa.Add(new Person { Age = 2, Name = "Jimmmy" });
    PLa.Add(new Person { Age = 1, Name = "Jim" });

    PLb.Add(new Person { Age = 1, Name = "Jim" });
    PLb.Add(new Person { Age = 3, Name = "Jim" });
    PLb.Add(new Person { Age = 2, Name = "Jimmmy" });

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ListSameIgnoreOrder(PLa, PLb));

}

public bool ListSameIgnoreOrder(List<Person> PLa, List<Person> PLb)
{
    if (PLa.Count != PLb.Count) return false;
    //PLa.Sort();
    //PLb.Sort();
    return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(PLa.OrderBy(s => s), PLb.OrderBy(s => s));
    //for (int i = 0; i < PLa.Count; i++)
    //{
    //    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
    //        PLa[i].Age.ToString() + " " + PLb[i].Age.ToString() + " " +
    //        PLa[i].Name + " " + PLb[i].Name);
    //    if (!PLa[i].Equals(PLb[i])) return false;
    //}
    //return true;
}

public class Person : object, IComparable
{
    private int age = 0;
    private string name = string.Empty;
    private int hash;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set 
        {
            if (age == value) return;
            age = value;
            CalcHash();
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set 
        { 
            if (name == value) return;
            name = value;
            CalcHash();
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        //Check for null and compare run-time types.
        if (obj == null || !(obj is Person)) return false;
        Person f = (Person)obj;
        if (f.Age != this.Age) return false;
        return (string.Compare(f.name, this.name) == 0);
    }

    private void CalcHash()
    {
        hash = Age.GetHashCode() ^
            (Name ?? String.Empty).GetHashCode();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return hash;
        //return age ^ name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Person otherPerson = obj as Person;
        if (otherPerson != null)
        {
            if (otherPerson.Age > this.Age) return -1;
            if (otherPerson.Age < this.Age) return 1;
            // compare all properties like above
            return string.Compare(otherPerson.name, this.name);
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Person");
    }
    public Person() { CalcHash(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
public bool EqualList(Dictionary<int, string> a, Dictionary<int, string> b)
{
    if (a.Count == b.Count)
    {
        bool rs = false;
        foreach (var i in a)
        {
            if (b.ContainsKey(i.Key))
            {
                rs = true;
            }
            else
            {
                rs = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return rs;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Usage:

```
if(EqualList(List<A>.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value), List<B>.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value)){

}else{

}
```

Comment: EqualList(List<A>.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value), List<B>.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value)