# Compare two complex list objects

Tags: c#, linq

How to check if two list of objects are same? I have list A and list B with same structure:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Details")]
public class Details
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "time")]
    public string time { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "duration")]
    public string duration { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Remark")]
public class Remark
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RemarkText")]
    public string RemarkText { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "isRemarkVisible")]
    public Boolean IsRemarkVisible { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "test")]
public class test
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Details Details { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Remark")]
    public Remark Remark { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Tests")]
public class Tests
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "test")]
    public test[] test { get; set; }
}
```

I convert it to list using linq.

**List A:**

```
Test
id=1
name=abc
details
    starttime=9.00
    endtime=12.00
    duration=1hr
Remark
    RemarkText= remark1 
    IsRemarkVisible=true
```

**List B:**

```
Test
id=1
name=abc
details
    starttime=9.00
    endtime=12.00
    duration=1hr
Remark
    RemarkText= remark2 
    IsRemarkVisible=true
```

Here both the lists are not same(remarkText field). I want a piece of code which will compare these two list and return whether same or no. How can i do that?

I tried using `List1.Except(List2)` but it doesn't compare.

**Edit**

I have created custom IEqualityComparer:

```
public class Compare : IEqualityComparer<test>
{
    public bool Equals(test x, test y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;

        bool equals = x.ID == y.ID && x.Name == y.Name && x.Remark == y.Remark
            && x.Details == y.Details;
        return equals;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(test codeh)
    {
        return (codeh.ID + codeh.Name + codeh.Remark + codeh.Details).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And

`var Comparer = new Compare();
List1.Except(List2, Comparer)` Should this work?

**Edit**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Details")]
public class Details
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "starttime")]
    public string starttime { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "endtime")]
    public string endtime { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "duration")]
    public string duration { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Remark")]
public class Remark
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RemarkText")]
    public string RemarkText { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "isRemarkVisible")]
    public Boolean IsRemarkVisible { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "test")]
public class test
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Details Details { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Remark")]
    public Remark Remark { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tags")]
    public Tags Tags { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Tags")]
public class Tags
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TagLocation")]
    public TagLocation[] TagLocation { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "TagLocation")]
public class TagLocation
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TagText")]
    public string TagText { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Tests")]
public class Tests
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "test")]
    public test[] test { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When are two objects equal? In general implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<YourType>` and pass it to `Except`.

Comment: If both the objects has same data. In my example if list B had remarkText= remark1

Comment: @TimSchmelter Would you please provide an example of how It has to done.

Comment: sure: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14236915/284240

Comment: how to pass IEqualityComparer<YourType> to Except

Comment: Create an instance and pass that: `List1.Except(List2, yourComparer)`

Comment: Could you please help me implementing custom IEqualityComparer. I have edited my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it doesn't work for me

Comment: Hope this question can answer your query. [Get list of matching objects from 3 different lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444334/get-list-of-matching-objects-from-3-different-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First modify your `test` class and implement (override) the `Equals` function. This will give you class the ability to compare itself with another object and tell whether both are same or not.

Ideally, each of your class should have its own `Equals` implementation, and the parent class should have no business of comparing the internals of child objects. But seeing that you need to compare only your `test` class, we implement all the comparison logic in the `test` class itself.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "test")]
public class test
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Details Details { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Remark")]
    public Remark Remark { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tags")]
    public Tags Tags { get; set; }

    // override object.Equals
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;

        // modify the code below to suit your needs...
        test objA = (test)obj;
        if (
                this.ID != objA.ID || this.Name != objA.Name
                || this.Details.duration != objA.Details.duration || this.Details.starttime != objA.Details.starttime || this.Details.endtime != objA.Details.endtime
                || this.Remark.IsRemarkVisible != objA.Remark.IsRemarkVisible || this.Remark.RemarkText != objA.Remark.RemarkText
            ) return false;
        if (this.Tags.TagLocation.Length != objA.Tags.TagLocation.Length) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Tags.TagLocation.Length; i++)
        {
            if (this.Tags.TagLocation[i].Id != objA.Tags.TagLocation[i].Id || this.Tags.TagLocation[i].TagText != objA.Tags.TagLocation[i].TagText) return false;
        }
        return true;    // if everything matched we infer that the objects are equal.
    }

    // override object.GetHashCode
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // modify the code below to generate a unique hash code for your object.
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can easily compare two objects of your test class easily.

e.g.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    test test1, test2, test3;

    test1 = new test { ID="1", Name ="abc"};
    test1.Details = new Details { duration = "1", starttime = "9.00", endtime = "12.00" };
    test1.Remark = new Remark { IsRemarkVisible = true, RemarkText = "remark1" };
    test1.Tags = new Tags();
    test1.Tags.TagLocation = new TagLocation[] 
    { 
         new TagLocation{ Id = "1", TagText = "tag1" },
         new TagLocation{ Id = "2", TagText = "tag2" } 
    }; 

    test2 = new test { ID = "1", Name = "abc" };
    test2.Details = new Details { duration = "1", starttime = "9.00", endtime = "12.00" };
    test2.Remark = new Remark { IsRemarkVisible = true, RemarkText = "remark2" };
    test2.Tags = new Tags();
    test2.Tags.TagLocation = new TagLocation[] 
    { 
         new TagLocation{ Id = "1", TagText = "tag1" },
         new TagLocation{ Id = "2", TagText = "tag2" } 
    }; 

    test3 = new test { ID = "1", Name = "abc" };
    test3.Details = new Details { duration = "1", starttime = "9.00", endtime = "12.00" };
    test3.Remark = new Remark { IsRemarkVisible = true, RemarkText = "remark2" };
    test3.Tags = new Tags();
    test3.Tags.TagLocation = new TagLocation[] 
    { 
         new TagLocation{ Id = "1", TagText = "tag1" },
         new TagLocation{ Id = "2", TagText = "tag2" } 
    }; 

    MessageBox.Show("test1.Equals(test2) ... " + test1.Equals(test2).ToString());   // shows false
    MessageBox.Show("test2.Equals(test3) ... " + test2.Equals(test3).ToString());   // shows true
}
```

Comment: Do I still need IEqualityComparer then?

Comment: No, you don't. You now have a method in your class named `Equals` and you can use it to compare two objects of your class.

Comment: I have edit my class object to have a third level to class. How would it differ then?

Comment: I just updated my answer and the code samples to suit your modified needs. Let me know is anything is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the inner classes do not have equality operator overloads `==`.

For example, `x.Details == y.Details` always returns `false`, no matter which data the instances hold, because the default `==` operator just calls the Equals method, which results in a reference equality, as defined in `object.Equals` method.

See [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx)

Also, there is an error in GetHashCode method. Never compute the hash codes with string concatenation. In addition, your don't overload the `ToString` method, so it just returns the same default string which is not useful for hash code computation.