# How to compare two c# lists data equal using linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have below two lists

```
List<TestData> objAPI = new List<TestData>{
                new TestData{ ID="50001",item="1001",dept="3"},
            };

List<TestData> objDatabase = new List<TestData>{
                new TestData{ ID="50001",item="1001",dept="3"},     
            };
```

and

```
 class TestData
    {

        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string item { get; set; }
        public string dept { get; set; }
    }
```

The scenario is: I have already data with ID=5001 in the table. When I get new data from API for ID 50001, need to compare new data with table data and if any of column(either item or dept column) has data difference then update table with new data.

I have table data in the list "objDatabase" and new data in "objAPI". How can i use Linq to perform this instaed of going for foreach  operation.

I tried below,but not working as expected.

```
var dd= objAPI.SequenceEqual(objDatabase);
```

Any help will be apprciated.

Comment: Msdn [`IEqualityComparer<T>` Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to check if two List<T> are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236672/fastest-way-to-check-if-two-listt-are-equal)

Comment: `SequenceEqual()` isn't magic. The individual elements of the sequence still must support value-equality unless identical objects are in fact the same instances. Either implement value-equality for the objects, or provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` for the `SequenceEqual()` method call, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14236915) in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `Equals` method. Otherwise `SequenceEqual` will only return true if the two lists contain the exact same objects.

You can override the Equals method like so:

```
class TestData
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string item { get; set; }
    public string dept { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is TestData other))
            return false;
            
        return ID == other.ID && item == other.item && dept == other.dept;      
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(ID, item, dept);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder sure, but did you know it doesn't use it?

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq you can do something like this

```
HashSet<int> hashDiff= new HashSet<int>(objDatabase.Select(s => s.Id));
var results = ObjAPI.Where(m => hashDiff.Contains(m.Id)).ToList();
```

This will give you all the data from objAPI which is duplicated in objDatabase and it will compare it using the ID.